# Jquery Post not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been working on Like and Unlike feature with jquery, ajax and php. My problem is little bit difficult to understand. Lets try to understand it first.

---

I have 2 php pages, `viewProfile.php` and `LikeMail.php`. `LikeMail.php` is being called by ajax function in `viewProfile.php`.

**Here is Section of viewProfile.php page's description**

```
                             -----------------
                            |   Like/Unlike   |
                             -----------------
```

Here is button  which actually comes from `LikeMail.php` by this ajax function

```
function like()
{
    var req  = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function()

    {
        if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById('Like').innerHTML=req.responseText;

        }
    }
    req.open('POST','LikeMail.php','true');
    req.send();
}
setInterval(function(){like()},1000);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Like"></div>
```

Output is being shown here in this div. *Button above may be `Like` or `Unlike` depends on the condition in `LikeMail.php` which will be described below in `LikeMail.php` description section.*

When one of them (buttons) `Like` or `Unlike` is clicked. It then calls respective jquery click function which sends post request to `LikeMail.php`.I have mentioned `Indirect` page in title because `Like` or `Unlike` buttons actually exists in `LikeMail.php` page. But due to ajax call these buttons are being shown in `viewProfile.php` page. So I then send post requests through `viewProfile.php` to actual page `LikeMail.php`
**It is jquery post for `Unlike` button**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#Unlike').unbind().click(function(){
        $.post("LikeMail.php",
            {Unlike: this.id},
            function(data){
                $('#response').html(data);
            }

        );

    });

});
```

**It is jquery post or `Like` button**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#Like').unbind().click(function(){
        $.post("LikeMail.php",
            {Like: this.id},
        function(data){
            $('#response').html(data);
        }
        );

    });

});
```

End of description section of `viewProfile.php` page

---

**Here is Section of LikeMail.php page's description**

`Like` or `Unlike` button is shown in `viewProfile.php` page depends upon this code:

```
$check_for_likes = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM liked WHERE user1='$user1' AND user2='$user2'");
                $numrows_likes = mysqli_num_rows($check_for_likes);
                if (false == $numrows_likes) {
                    echo mysqli_error($conn);
                }

                if ($numrows_likes >= 1) {
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="Unlike" value="Unlike" id="Unlike" class="btn btn-lg btn-info edit">';


                }

                elseif ($numrows_likes == 0) {
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="Like" value="Like" id="Like" class="btn btn-lg btn-info edit">';
                }
```

Button depends upon these two above conditions.

Now when `Like` button is clicked, post request from `viewProfile.php` comes here

```
if(isset($_POST['Like']))   //When Like button in viewProfile.php is clicked then this peace of code inside if condition should run and insert some record in database
            {
                $total_likes = $total_likes+1;
                $like = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE user SET user_Likes = '$total_likes' WHERE user_id = '$user2'");
                $user_likes = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO liked (user1,user2) VALUES ('$user1','$user2')");
                $query3 = "INSERT INTO notification (user1, user2, alert, notificationType) VALUE ('$user1','$user2','unchecked','like')";
                if (mysqli_query($conn, $query3)) {
                    echo "Like";
                } else {
                    echo mysqli_error($conn);
                }

            }
```

Similarly when `Unlike` button is clicked. This peace of code should run.

```
if(isset($_POST['Unlike'])) //This is the condition for Unlike button. It should delete record from databse
            {
                $total_likes = $total_likes-2;
                $like = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE user SET user_Likes='$total_likes' WHERE user_id='$user2'");
                $remove_user = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM liked WHERE user1='$user1' AND user2='$user2'");
                $query3 = "DELETE FROM notification WHERE user1='$user1' AND user2='$user2' AND notificationType='like'";

                $check = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
                if ($check) {
                    echo "Unlike";
                } else {
                    echo mysqli_error($conn);
                }
            }
```

**Problem:**
Main problem which I faced is that when I click `Like` or `Unlike` both executes the condition of `Like` button code. Both inserts the data into database as `Unlike` condition should delete data from database but it also inserts data as condition for `Like` button do. Kindly can you please help me that how to tackle this problem. Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
When I delete all the respective code for `Like` button. The condition for `Unlike` button starts working correctly.

Comment: Summary to People can easily focus main issue

Comment: @kollein Summery is described after `Problem` heading

Comment: You need to trace your variable to check where they are corrupted, or wich condition is erroneous. Use and abuse `print_r()` and `error_log()` on PHP side, and `alert()` or `console.log()` on javascript.

Comment: You have a div with an id="like", do you have a button with the same id?

Comment: @Dimitri It just fetching all the data from `LikeMail.php` page

Comment: You must change ID OF DIV in viewProfile.php so

Comment: I have changed it `Like` to `like1` but now it stops working

Comment: Before it executed `Like` button functionality. Not completely stopped working

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a duplicated ID somewhere, perhaps the DIV. Take a look at this.

```
<div id="Like_2"></div>

<input type="submit" name="Unlike" value="Unlike" id="Unlike" class="btn btn-lg btn-info edit">

<input type="submit" name="Like" value="Like" id="Like" class="btn btn-lg btn-info edit">

<div id="response"></div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#Unlike', function(){
        $('#response').html(this.id);
        //ajax call

    });
    $(document).on('click','#Like', function(){
        $('#response').html(this.id);
        //ajax call

    });
});
```

And the javascript function:

```
function like()
{
    var req  = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function()

    {
        if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById('Like_2').innerHTML=req.responseText;

        }
    }
    req.open('POST','LikeMail.php','true');
    req.send();
}
setInterval(function(){like()},1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/2103/

Comment: Can it be a problem when I send request through `viewProfile.php` page?

Comment: Not sure, you'll have to use F12 to open the developer tools to see what is it that you're sending to the backend. But from what you're describing seems to be a duplicate ID somewhere.

Comment: First it works. But now both buttons stops working and console is blank

Comment: What do you mean the stop working? You mean they don't fire the ajax requests anymore?

Comment: jquery dont fire post requests now

Comment: Check out the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/2123/). The buttons are now binding properly. The post requests should work if they're put back. Although you'll get some 404 errors in the console, you'll see that they're sending their proper post data.

Comment: I think problem is that I send post request from indirect page

Comment: This is a possibility, but couldn't tell you for sure where the problem is coming from. If buttons are being loaded from somewhere else, then you'll need to check how they're being loaded. As is, the buttons like I've shown you work fine, but might break if they're being dynamically loaded (which I don't think is a problem here). There might be some other underlying cause.